# String reverse, std::string does not allow character assignment?

Tags: c++, stdstring

This is my code to reverse a string using `std::string`. But it does not work..

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

main()
{
   string input;
   int i, j;
   cout << "Enter a string: ";
   getline(cin,input);

   string output;
   for(i = 0, j = input.length() - 1; i < input.length(); i++, j--)
      output[i]=input[j];

   cout << "Reversed string = " << output;
   cin.get();
}
```

But if we replace string output as `char output[100];` it works. So `std::string` does not allow character assignments?

Comment: You should allocate memory for `output`.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this was too cowardly to leave a comment, so just to point out some things that’s wrong with this question which might earn a downvote: you made no effort to format your code properly. Your code is invalid C++ to begin with. Your code isn’t reduced to a minimum to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to resize output:

```
output.resize(input.length());
```

or initially set length:

```
string output(input.length(), ' ');

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

main(){
string input;
int i,j;
cout << "Enter a string: ";
getline(cin,input);
string output(input.length(), ' '); // initially set sufficient length
for(i=0,j=input.length()-1;i<input.length();i++,j--)
output[i]=input[j];

cout << "Reversed string = " << output;
cin.get();
}
```

See also:
[std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/)

Comment: What is the second argument in the constructor of the std::string? Why is it an blank character? :)

Comment: It's character to fill string with. std::string(n, c) gives string of character c n times.

Answer (score 10):

`std::string` allows character assignments, but not beyond the end of the string. Since `std::string output;` creates an empty string, `output[0]` is beyond the end of the string.

Presumably this is a learning exercise, but you may as well also be aware of some tools that will do it for you:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::string input;
    std::getline(cin,input);
    std::cout << "input: " << input << '\n';

    std::reverse(input.begin(), input.end());
    std::cout << "reversed: " << input << '\n';
}
```

or:

```
#include <iterator>
...

    std::string output;
    std::reverse_copy(input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(output));
    std::cout << "reversed: " << output << '\n';
```

or:

```
    std::string output;
    std::copy(input.rbegin(), input.rend(), std::back_inserter(output));
```

or:

```
    std::string output(input.rbegin(), input.rend());
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `output` is an empty string `output[i]` will access invalid memory location. Simply append the character to the `output` string using `output += input[j]`.

Answer (score 3):

Have a try on the STL algorithm of reverse?

```
include <algorithm>
// ...
std::string str("hello world!");
std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

After constructing `string output;` it have 0 length. You need to resize it to `input.length()`.

```
string output;
output.resize(input.length());
```

Resizing is faster then appending char by char, but you have to know the size first.