# reversing char array caused access violation

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I just wanted to write a code for reversing a char array(or a pointer char . i failed so used char arrays) . like "USAF" gonna be "FAUS" first i did this with pointers so i got access violation  .

CODE :

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int getlength(char *);
void reverse (char * ch );

int main ()
{
    char  *ch ="USAF";
    /*cout<<*ch;*/

    int len = getlength(ch);
    reverse(ch);

    cout<<"Reverse :";


    for(int i =0;i <len; i++)
        cout<<*(ch + i);

    cin.get();

}


int getlength(char * ch)
{
    int len=0;
     char *address = ch;
    for(; *(ch)!='\0' ; ch++)
        len++;

    ch=address;
    return len;
}

void reverse(char *ch )
{
    char tmp;
    int i,j,len=getlength(ch);

    for(i=0;i<(len/2);i++)
        for(j=len-1;j>(len/2);j--){
            tmp=*(ch+i);
            *(ch+i)=*(ch+j); //ACCESS VIOLATED 
            *(ch+j)=tmp;


        }
```

and why that happens? ch+i and + j are in length of the char pointer (array really what should i call it at the moment?) but it throws a c ?

and my current code is almost pointer free but as arrays are somehow pointer and they re called by reference so i guess i did it :

```
   #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void reverse (char ch [],int len);

int main ()
{
    char  ch [] ="USAF";
    int len = sizeof(ch);
    reverse(ch,len);

    cout<<"Reverse :";

    for(int i =0;i <len; i++)
        cout<<ch[i];
    cin.get();

}



 void reverse(char ch [],int len)
{

    int i,j; 
    char tmp;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        cout<<*(ch+i);

    cout<<*(ch+(3-1));


for(i=0;i<(len/2);i++)
for(j=len-1 ; j>(len/2);j--){

tmp = ch[i];
ch[i]=ch[j];
ch[j]=tmp;

}
```

but when i compile it shows : "F AUS" its so strange from where that blank character appeared  ? (some cout lines are just leftovers  dont mind em)

PS: This is my first post in stackoverflow(cool name btw :) ) . i really enjoyed pro atmosphere here and found it a good place to ask my own questions + when i get a good deal of knowledge answer others.

Comment: This is more C than C++ TBH. Is there a reason for it?

Comment: `char  *ch ="USAF";` is deprecated in C++ and allowed only for backwards compatibility with C. You should use `const char  *ch ="USAF";` and viola, a bug is revealed!

Comment: @luk32 well my reference used such . btw im interested to learn c . its cool .

Comment: have also a look on the [C++ way of reversing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10682311/2932052)

Answer (score 1):

The variable `ch` points to a string literal, which is an array of *constant* characters. In other words, attempting to change it will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Instead when declare it as an array, like

```
char ch[] = "USAF";
```

then the compiler creates the string on the stack and it's not constant so you can change the contents of the array.

Comment: **Yes:** UB, but I think it's also bad style to treat string literals as arrays of chars.

Comment: @wolf so using c style has no benefits? can i just abandon and go for string class in full?

Comment: @KNOWN-SOURCE I think you should definitely learn to use `std::string` and all its benefits - be sure you'll love it. Ah, and you should also try `cout << ch` :-)

Answer (score 0):

http://cpp.sh/3ekd

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int getlength(char *);
void reverse(char * ch);

int main()
{
    char  ch[] = "USAF";
    /*cout<<*ch;*/

    int len = getlength(ch);
    reverse(ch);

    cout << "Reverse :";


    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        cout << *(ch + i);

    cin.get();

}


int getlength(char * ch)
{
    int len = 0;
    char *address = ch;
    for (; *(ch) != '\0'; ch++)
        len++;

    ch = address;
    return len;
}

void reverse(char *ch)
{
    int len = getlength(ch);

    for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
        char c = ch[i];
        ch[i] = ch[len - i - 1];
        ch[len - i - 1] = c;
    }
}
```